# Empathy can't connect to facebook

Tags: empathy, facebook

I have problem with the Empathy, on Ubuntu 12.04!
I try to login with my Facebook information. 
I receive message (I use my Ubuntu in Bulgarian language) "Unable to identify the registration Facebook"...
My pass and account name is correct...
Please help!

Comment: Possible bug ? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/970314

Answer (score 2):

Are you logging in with your email address or by your username?  Empathy requires you to log in with your username, which can be found in your personal information on facebook.  Try logging in with your username and see if you still have the same problem.